# How do I get a URL over HTTP with netcat?

Tags: http, nc

Can anybody tell me why I am getting `bad request` while executing this command

```
echo -e "GET http://www.yellowpages.com.eg/Mjg3NF9VUkxfMTEwX2h0dHA6Ly93d3cubG90dXMtYWlyLmNvbV8=/Lotus-Air/profile.html HTTP/1.1\n\n" | nc www.yellowpages.com 80
```

The same web site opens fine in the browser.

Comment: Your example domains are inconsistent. You are telling nc to use a .com and sending a get request for .com.eg. Typo?

Comment: Your example URL does NOT work in a browser for me, it gets forwarded somewhere else. What result do you expect back?

Comment: @Caleb : I was expecting 302 instead of 400

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341518/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-manually-with-netcat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The headers in an HTTP request must use CRLF (Windows) line endings. (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_message) or [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).) Many servers support LF (Unix) line endings as an extension, but not this one.

In addition, HTTP 1.1 requires a `Host:` header line, as [Warren Young pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15799/simple-problem-with-netcat-tool/15809#15809). (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Client_request) or [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)).

```
echo -e "GET http://www.yellowpages.com.eg/Mjg3NF9VUkxfMTEwX2h0dHA6Ly93d3cubG90dXMtYWlyLmNvbV8=/Lotus-Air/profile.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.yellowpages.com.eg\r\n\r\n" | nc www.yellowpages.com 80
```

or more legibly

```
sed $'s/$/\r/' <<EOF | nc www.yellowpages.com 80
GET http://www.yellowpages.com.eg/Mjg3NF9VUkxfMTEwX2h0dHA6Ly93d3cubG90dXMtYWlyLmNvbV8=/Lotus-Air/profile.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yellowpages.com.eg

EOF
```

But why not use wget or curl, which will construct a valid request without sweating and still allow you to specify custom headers if necessary?

Comment: The important part here for me is to note the "\r\n" in the example command. I see that you mentioned CRLF at the start of your answer, but I suspect it's possible that some people might miss the "\r\n" in the long command, which is what I was missing simply because it works well enough with "\n" alone on some servers.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the domain name in your GET request. You have told `nc` the domain name you are connecting to do it knows where to go find the server, but `nc` doesn't pass that on to the server. If the server is hosting multiple domains, it will not know which one to send you. The request header you are passing with `echo` should include this full domain like this:

```
echo "GET http://domain.tld/path" | nc domain.tld 80
```

Note that you can also drop the `-e` argument to your echo and the escaped newlines at the end. The `-e` is suppressing echo's natural tendency to add a newline, then you are adding one yourself.

**Edit 1:** Is there some reason you are not using a normal download tool like `curl` that can handle all the header possibilities and give you useful output? Do you really need to handle the header chat yourself? `curl http://domain.tld/path` should give you much more reliable output because the programmers have already worked through all the possibilities for you.

**Edit 2:** See [Warren's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15799/simple-problem-with-netcat-tool/15809#15809) for information about the protocol specification. TL;DR: If you specify 1.1, you have to then comply with that protocal. If you pecify 1.0, you can usually make the reqest as above.

The make a requestion with echo and netcat using HTTP/1.1, try this:

```
echo "GET http://domain.tld/path HTTP/1.1\nHost: domain.tld\n" | nc domain.tld 80
```

Comment: I did even then the same error

Comment: echo -e "GET http://www.yellowpages.com.eg/Mjg3NF9VUkxfMTEwX2h0dHA6Ly93d3cubG90dXMtYWlyLmNvbV8=/Lotus-Air/profile.html HTTP/1.1\n\n" | nc www.yellowpages.com 80

Comment: Your examples aren't full things I can copy and paste to test, but this does work. Try this example EXACTLY: `echo "GET http://www.google.com.tr/" | nc www.google.com.tr 80`

Answer (score 4):

HTTP 1.1 [requires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) that you send at least a `Host` header in GET requests. That is, the minimum legal request looks like this:

```
GET http://www.example.com/noise/and/junk HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

(Plus an additional CRLF to terminate the header section, of course.)

There may be HTTP servers that will cope with a request claiming to require HTTP 1.1 but that doesn't include a `Host` header, but your server is correct to reject such a request.

`Host` is an HTTP 1.1 extension which was needed to support name-based virtual hosting. If the site you're trying to access has dedicated servers (or at least, a dedicated IP), you can safely drop back to HTTP 1.0, which lets you make a single-line HTTP request:

```
GET http://www.example.com/noise/and/junk HTTP/1.0
```